# "Advance" an Excel formula via keyboard shortcut while in edit mode?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, keyboard-shortcuts

In the screenshot below, I have a simple SUM formula in Excel that needs to be "advanced" by a single column to include the December value in the calculation. Once in edit mode (shown), is there a keyboard shortcut in Excel to advance this SUM function by one (moving to the right) to capture the next column's value? I know I can use my mouse to drag the blue box over to the right, but I'm looking for a solution from the keyboard.

Obviously, I'm imagining the answer (if one exists) would apply to other formulas in Excel beyond just SUM.

---

### My Question:

While in **Edit Mode** in Excel, for any formula that requires an array for an argument (e.g. `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.), can I expand the existing array using a keyboard shortcut?

For example, in my screenshot below, I would like to expand `EC64:EM64` to `EC64:EN64` using *just* a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible? If so, how?

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Was `December` column/data added *after* you entered your `SUM()` formula? ...anyways, you could probably just hit `ALT+=` on your keyboard.  This will automatically make the assumption the data to the left of that cell you do this on wants to be added.  (Note: this is specific to the `SUM()` formula).

Comment: @BruceWayne - the December data was entered before I entered the `SUM` formula...we wait until the month is over to change out the projected amount to the actual amount, then we update the formula to include the month we just closed out. I'm working on a VBA solution, but in the meantime, would like to see if there's a keyboard shortcut

Comment: for `SUM()` specifically the `ALT =` shortcut should work.

Comment: I know that `Alt =` works as a shortcut for the `SUM` formula if you're wanting to sum up an entire row or column, but in this example, I just want to be able to increment the formula by 1 additional column. It just so happens that, by adding December's value, it amounts to the same. But back in October, for instance, I would have only wanted the 2017 Totals column to just sum through September. Not the entire row

Comment: There was a different post on here that found the last populated cell, if the you combine that with indirect() then it could become automatic picking up the latest value. Or, you could try an approach with a countif() to find all values greater than zero for example and build the range from that...

Comment: That would definitely work, @SolarMike, if it weren't for the fact that all the months have values during the year, but once a month we update each month from a _proposed_ value to the _actual_ value and update the `SUM` formula to include that new value in the YTD calculation.

Comment: What if for your proposed values, you include an asterisk or something? Or I was thinking to do a formula that looks at the current month (using `TODAY()`), and sees if the header months are "less than" that. If so, sum, otherwise ignore. But I'm having trouble wrapping that in a formula.

Comment: Is the end intent to automatically include any new columns added in future to the left of the Totals column?

Comment: That could work, @BruceWayne - but what I'm really after in this question, though, is that for _any_ formula in Excel that requires an array for an argument (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.), can I expand that array using just my keys when I'm in edit mode?

Comment: @jeffreyweir - see my response above about the end intent. I really just want to be able to expand or contract the "array box" for an Excel formula's argument - not using my mouse to drag the array box corners. I know this can be done with a mouse, but I'm wondering if my keys can provide the same functionality

Comment: So it's just a one-time thing? i.e. you won't be expanding these formulas again in future to include new columns? Reason I ask is that it is certainly possible to write a formula using INDEX giving a dynamic range that automatically sums all columns to the left, that is robust to column insertions. Just checking whether that is the end intent.

Comment: That could definitely work, @jeffreyweir - but with all due respect, you're way over-thinking it! Probably my fault for not properly wording the question. I just want to know if, in edit mode, can I expand a formula that already includes an array. In this case, I'd want to expand that formula to the right by 1 column using just the keyboard

Comment: Seems strange to me to want a keyboard shortcut to do what a dynamic range could do automaticaly. I see above you want update the formula to include the month you just closed out. It would be simple to build a dynamic range that references a named range called "LastMonth" that builds the range for you, thus completely removing the requirement for you to update the range manually.

Comment: I see what you're saying. And I'm actually working on building out a solution in VBA that will automatically increment the `SUM` function by 1 every month, thus eliminating the need to do this update manually. But here's the odd thing: when I first enter a `SUM` function into Excel, I get the "dancing ants" effect, which allow me to use my keyboard to expand/collapse the input array freely. But if I try and go back and edit that formula, the dancing ants go away and I'm left with, presumably, only my mouse to expand the input array.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - That's a great idea! I'd throw that in an answer for sure. OP could even use that reference cell to put a formula of `=TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-1),"mmmm")`

Answer (score 0):

Using just your keyboard, as requested, you can do the following:

When on the cell that holds your formula (`EO64` in your example), press <kbd>F2</kbd>. You should now be in **Edit Mode**, verified in the bottom left of your Excel window (if **Edit Mode** doesn't appear, right-click the status bar in Excel and select *Cell Mode* if it's unchecked).

Next, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> to highlight the part of the range you want to change (`EM64` in your example).

Now press <kbd>F2</kbd> again to activate **Enter Mode**. Use the arrow keys to move the "marching ants" into the cell you want to modify the existing range with (you'll notice that **Enter Mode** now changes to **Point Mode**). In your example, it appears to be `EN64`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Your range should now be updated accordingly.

---

I agree with the comments above regarding using a formula, but as you asked for a keyboard shortcut, hopefully this can accomplish what you need for it to.

Comment: When you say `Shift` + `<`, do you mean `Left arrow`? Or actually use the less than symbol?

Comment: My mistake. I corrected it above. I meant `left arrow`.

Comment: That's almost it! I can get the **Enter Mode** to activate, but when I try and advance the marching ants with my keys, it either starts at the beginning (January, in this case), or it will auto-fill all the way down to December. In the screenshot above, this works out. But in general, I want the marching ants to pick up exactly where my old range was and allow me to increment using the keys - instead of having to re-input the range from **Enter Mode**

Comment: Outside of the above solution, I don't personally know if this is possible. My method would allow you to highlight the first part of the range (`EC64`) to adjust the *upper-left anchor* of said range, or highlight the second part of the range (`EM64`) and effectively adjust the *lower-right anchor* of the range. Either way, once you're in **Enter Mode** and you have a valid portion of the argument highlighted, you can use any of the arrow keys to change one of the two "anchors" in the formula.